# Upload File with extra parameters to AWS S3 using iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Just like on a regular HTTP POST request. we can add unlimited parameters as form data. How about when uploading using the iOS AWS S3 SDK?

My iOS function

```
let uploadRequest            = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest();
uploadRequest?.body          = NSURL(string: "file://\(path)") as URL!;
uploadRequest?.key           = "file_name";
uploadRequest?.bucket        = aws_s3_bucket_path;
uploadRequest?.contentType   = "image/" + file_extension;
```

Is there any way I can add more parameters to send to my Lambda Function?

Comment: What type of extra parameter do you want to add?

Comment: Hi Karthick, like title for the photo, caption, user info who uploaded it. Is there a way?

Comment: No you can create the group/folder in `AWS S3` using `key` property. like `folderName/FoderName/FileName`.

Comment: I'm sorry if you misunderstood. The path/key is already good. but I just need to pass extra information to lambda for post processing. Like so lambda can  add to the database more information about the photo. like add caption, title, etc...

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You can `add extra parameters` as `metaData` to you request.

```
let uploadRequest            = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest();
uploadRequest?.body          = NSURL(string: "file://\(path)") as URL!;
uploadRequest?.key           = "file_name";
uploadRequest?.bucket        = aws_s3_bucket_path;
uploadRequest?.contentType   = "image/" + file_extension;
uploadRequest?.metadata      = ["PhotoTitle" : " testName", "PhotoCaption" : "TestCaption", "UserName" : "TestName", "UserAge" : "TestAge"]
```

Thanks:)

Comment: Hi sir.. I've read that metadata will be permanently set to the file. I'm trying to pass an access token too which I don't want to be attached to a file . Thanks a lot bro

Comment: do you want to add access token of file?

Comment: Just to pass it so I can use it for validation purposes... if there's a way to reset a metadata then it could be a workaround for me.. do you think after I set metadata from iOS I can later reset it from node js?

Comment: Sorry bro I dont know about node js. You can do indirectly by getting the meta data of already uploaded file and edit that metadata if you want and the upload different file to s3. Delete older one. Just a suggestion.